# Domino Server on Mac OS X (Using Crossover and Domino4Wine)

Tags: macos, xpages, cross-platform, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to get running my domino notes, Designer, Administrator and Server on my Mac with the help of [Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-mac?utm_expid=4394146-29.8F0qkWU6SbSEgujXg6sJGQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeweavers.com%2Fproducts%2Fcrossover-mac%2Fdownload) and the tutorial on [Domino4Wine](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-mac?utm_expid=4394146-29.8F0qkWU6SbSEgujXg6sJGQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeweavers.com%2Fproducts%2Fcrossover-mac%2Fdownload). Installation went smoothly with the windows exe files and the server was configured correctly.

However, it seems that the HTTP server is not running, since when I hit the localhost, instead of seeing the IBM page, it just gives standard error when the server is not running. However, when I hit the ***load http*** command, it says Already Running. This is the first attempt of configuring it in my mac. Would be really nice to see everything running.

Is this a bug? or is there something I am missing?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Update based on Answer @stwissel

@Remark 1: That would be kinda the best alternative now, I am just trying to explore if this works out, otherwise that is always a fallback step.

@Remark 2: Already checked that, in-fact also tried port 81,8080 and 8000 with no success. It seems that all the ports are blocked on the Windows XP local to the bottle of crossover (since, even the port-scanner app installed on Windows crashes down with no reason).

@Remark 3: I am not sure here, could it be that all ports are to be given rights explicitly? (since I tried other ports too)

Answer (score 5):

Remark 1: Don't bother, use a Linux virtual machine
Remark 2: Check your local HTTP server. OS/X runs a local http server that might prevent the http stack to bind to port 80
Remark 3: On OS/X port 80 needs admin rights

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just updated my question accordingly. Any suggestions there? (Remark 1 seems the best choice)

Comment: I don't know how to run Crossover tasks with higher privileges. One of the reasons why I use a VM

Comment: Yea, lets see, that should be my fallback step. I have raised the request on Domino4Wine and Crossover, if anything comes up, would be good for future. Thank you for your time.